# sql query to find the orders processed by the employees

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL  query  to  list  the  employees  and  the  quantity  of  orders  that  they  proceeded  in  the  database. The output list must include employee ID, name, and the quantity of orders. The list must be sorted by the quantity of orders in the descending order. i have quoted the required tables below.

```
CREATE TABLE employees
  (
    employee_id NUMBER 
                GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 108 
                PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    last_name  VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    email      VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    phone      VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    hire_date  DATE NOT NULL          ,
    manager_id NUMBER( 12, 0 )        , -- fk
    job_title  VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_employees_manager 
        FOREIGN KEY( manager_id )
        REFERENCES employees( employee_id )
        ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
-- product category
CREATE TABLE product_categories
  (
    category_id NUMBER 
                GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 6 
                PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR2( 255 ) NOT NULL
  );

-- products table
CREATE TABLE products
  (
    product_id NUMBER 
               GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 289 
               PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name  VARCHAR2( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    description   VARCHAR2( 2000 )        ,
    standard_cost NUMBER( 9, 2 )          ,
    list_price    NUMBER( 9, 2 )          ,
    category_id   NUMBER NOT NULL         ,
    CONSTRAINT fk_products_categories 
      FOREIGN KEY( category_id )
      REFERENCES product_categories( category_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
-- customers
CREATE TABLE customers
  (
    customer_id NUMBER 
                GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 320 
                PRIMARY KEY,
    name         VARCHAR2( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    address      VARCHAR2( 255 )         ,
    website      VARCHAR2( 255 )         ,
    credit_limit NUMBER( 8, 2 )
  );

CREATE TABLE orders
  (
    order_id NUMBER 
             GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 106 
             PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id NUMBER( 6, 0 ) NOT NULL, -- fk
    status      VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
    salesman_id NUMBER( 6, 0 )         , -- fk
    order_date  DATE NOT NULL          ,
    CONSTRAINT fk_orders_customers 
      FOREIGN KEY( customer_id )
      REFERENCES customers( customer_id )
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_orders_employees 
      FOREIGN KEY( salesman_id )
      REFERENCES employees( employee_id ) 
      ON DELETE SET NULL
  );
-- order items
CREATE TABLE order_items
  (
    order_id   NUMBER( 12, 0 )                                , -- fk
    item_id    NUMBER( 12, 0 )                                ,
    product_id NUMBER( 12, 0 ) NOT NULL                       , -- fk
    quantity   NUMBER( 8, 2 ) NOT NULL                        ,
    unit_price NUMBER( 8, 2 ) NOT NULL                        ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_order_items 
      PRIMARY KEY( order_id, item_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_items_products 
      FOREIGN KEY( product_id )
      REFERENCES products( product_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_items_orders 
      FOREIGN KEY( order_id )
      REFERENCES orders( order_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

what i have tried.

```
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       E.FIRSTNAME
       || ' '
       || E.LASTNAME,
       SUM(OI.QUANTITY * OI.UNITPRICE) AS TOTAL_SALES
  FROM ORDERS O
  JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = O.SALESMAN_ID
  JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI ON O.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
 GROUP BY E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
          E.FIRSTNAME,
          E.LASTNAME
 ORDER BY TOTAL_SALES DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: `JOIN.JOIN.JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GROUP BY`, `AGGREGATION` function, and `ORDER BY` as follows:

```
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       E.FIRSTNAME
       || ' '
       || E.LASTNAME,
       SUM(OI.QUANTITY * OI.UNITPRICE) AS TOTAL_SALES
  FROM ORDERS O
  JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = O.SALESMAN_ID
  JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI ON O.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
 GROUP BY E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
          E.FIRSTNAME,
          E.LASTNAME
 ORDER BY 3 DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: theres some missing expression in line 12. Am unable to find

Comment: Try the column number in ORDER BY as updated in the latest answer

Answer (score 0):

Can u try like this ;

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
   EMPNAME,
   TOTAL_SALES
FROM (
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
   E.FIRSTNAME
   || ' '
   || E.LASTNAME EMPNAME,
   SUM(OI.QUANTITY * OI.UNITPRICE) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM ORDERS O
JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = O.SALESMAN_ID
JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI ON O.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
GROUP BY E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
      E.FIRSTNAME,
      E.LASTNAME)
ORDER BY TOTAL_SALES DESC NULLS LAST;
```